# Can Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials be deployed as standalone (not in a domain)?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, licensing, workgroup

We purchased a new server. Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials was installed by the ISV, and whenever I log in, I'm prompted to complete the post-deployment configuration, yet it appears I can only create a domain or join one, not operate as a standalone (workgroup) server.

Is it possible to use Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials without joining or creating a domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it can't. That unfortunately is not explicity stated in the WS2012E website or in the requirements document, but under [Install and Configure Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn281793.aspx):

The Windows Server Essentials Experience role in Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials or Windows Server 2012 R2 has the following limitations:

- Must be the domain controller at the root of the forest and domain, and must hold all the FSMO roles.
- Cannot be installed in an environment with a pre-existing Active Directory domain (however, there is a grace period of 21 days for performing migrations).
- Can only be deployed into a single domain.
- A read-only domain controller cannot exist in your domain.

As a workaround, you can try following the steps detailed [here](http://winsupersite.com/article/windowsserver2012/windows-server-2012-essentials-connect-client-pcs-domain-144329) to allow machines outside the domain to access resources of this server.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding possible : No sir. As you should have learned from reading just about any of the technical documentation about the product that you bought, you would know that a server with Essentials on it ***is*** a domain controller, which, by definition, means that it must be in a domain.

Regarding licensing : such questions are explicitly off-topic here for reasons that are well-detailed if you will be so kind as to read the "help" link at the top of every page here.